# awk solution for comparing current line to next line and printing one of the lines based on a condition

Tags: awk, getline

I have an input file that looks like this (first column is a location number and the second is a count that should increase over time):

```
1       0
1       2
1       6
1       7
1       7
1       8
1       7
1       7
1       9
1       9
1       10
1       10
1       9
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       9
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
```

and I'd like to fix it look like this (substitute counts that decreased with the previous count):

```
1       0
1       2
1       6
1       7
1       7
1       8
1       8
1       8
1       9
1       9
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
1       10
```

I've been trying to use awk for this, but am stumbling with getline since I can't seem to figure out how to reset the line number (NR?) so it'll read each line and it's next line, not two lines at a time. This is the code I have so far, any ideas?

```
awk '{a=$1; b=$2; getline; c=$1; d=$2; if (a==c && b<=d) print a"\t"b; else print c"\t"d}' original.txt > fixed.txt
```

Also, this is the output I'm currently getting:

```
1       0
1       6
1       7
1       7
1       9
1       10
1       9
1       10
1       10
1       9
1       10
1       10
1       10
```

Comment: Ok, just to clarify, are you trying to *skip* the lines where the count decreases? That's a lot of lines, I wonder if you could give a shorter example that would be just as clear?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear, I want to print the previous line when the count decreases, so end up with the same number of lines but with a file where the count stays put or increases, but never decreases.

Comment: I got it .. check out the answers provided below, I think you'll find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps all you want is:

```
awk '$2 < p { $2 = p } { p = $2 } 1' input-file
```

This will fail on the first line if the value in the second column is negative, so do:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $2 < p ...'
```

This simply sets the second column to the previous value if the current value is less, then stores the current value in the variable p, then prints the line.

Note that this also slightly modifies the spacing of the output on lines that change.  If your input is tab-separated, you might want to do:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $2 < p { $2 = p } { p = $2 } 1' OFS=\\t input-file
```

Comment: Wow .. so much more concise .. I think I have the verbose version of your first solution

Comment: Fantastic, I was just trying to figure the spacing out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This script will do what you like:

```
{
  if ($2 < prev_count)
    $2 = prev_count
  else
    prev_count = $2

  printf("%d   %d\n", $1, $2)
}
```

This is a verbose version to be easily readable :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the verbose version as well!

Comment: @suegene Happy to help .. I adjusted the output spacing with `printf` which may give you a bit more finer control over the format/spacing if you need it.